# Using art_nav as a generic controller for car-like robots

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was looking for a ROS package which I could use as a Controller for a 4-wheeled indoor car-like robot.

We have a system which integrates a path planner, localizer,  controller and other modules needed for navigation. However, the Controller doesn't work too well. Hence I was thinking if i could use another Controller and maybe modify that to the project's needs, it might work better.

In that regard, how feasible is it to use the art_nav package (which was built for the ART autonomous vehicle) for a generic 4-wheeled robot ? Is there some Documentation for the design of the algorithm ?

Are there any other Controllers ROS packages that I should take a look at ?

Thanks,
Sagnik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10414/using-art_nav-as-a-generic-controller-for-car-like-robots/) by [Sagnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/183/sagnik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 184 on 2011-06-27

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-06-27**:
Probably a fantastic question for @joq, Let's see if we can get him in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That package was originally written in 2007 for the DARPA Urban Challenge competition [[Beeson et al., JoPhA, March 2008]](http://personal.traclabs.com/%7Epbeeson/publications/b2hd-Beeson-jopha-08.html). A substantial subset of it was later ported to ROS without changing the basic design.

The design is quite specific to the Urban Challenge rules and file formats. I don't expect it would help much for an indoor robot. Most of the navigation is for driving down road segments using GPS and a Road Network Definition File (i.e. road map) defined by DARPA, while obeying California traffic laws.

We would like `art_nav` to use more generic map interface than the `art_map` package currently provides. Working with several other ROS development groups, we are designing an experimental [Geographic Information API](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cartography/Reviews/2011-06-18_API_Review) for satellite-based mapping and navigation. That does not apply to indoor robots, either, but you are welcome to participate if your other interests intersect.

The code works on our car, and could probably be ported to another with reasonable effort. It depends on lower-level packages (`art_pilot`, `art_servo`) which provide fairly generic car-like interfaces (brake, shifter, Ackermann steering, throttle). Servo drivers for those devices would need to be written.

I am interested in working with you or other ROS developers on generic navigation for 4-wheeled vehicles using Ackermann drive. While some of our existing code might be useful and you are welcome to it, I expect a generic package to involve substantial redesign.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sagnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/183/sagnik/) on 2011-06-28**:
Thank you for the information.